# PyTorch CUDA out of memory VRAM is not freed after calculations

Tags: python, pytorch

I train and evaluate transformers and RNNs per k-fold cross-validation in PyTorch. After some model calculations (the entire model has been trained and evaluated with some hyperparameters), I always get a CUDA out of memory error when computing the next model (with new hyperparameters). This even happens if I start running a completely different *ipython* notebook containing a different model.

Here is the error:

```
RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 312.00MiB (GPU 0; 8.00 GiB total capacity; 6.21 GiB already allocated; 0 bytes free; 6.37GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)
```

Somehow the VRAM is not getting freed. I already tried:

```
torch.cuda.empty_cache()
```

but it did not work. The error most often occurs during training, so the torch.no_grad() is not an option. The only thing that works is restarting the PC and then calculating the next model. But this is not really a long-term solution. Has anyone a better solution than restarting the PC after every few model calculations to free the VRAM?

Specs:

```
Windows 10 PRO
RTX3070
AMD Rysen 7 3800XT
32Gb DDR4 3200MH/z
Pytorch 1.10, CUDA 11.3
Python 3.9.0
```

Here is one of the defined model architectures and the train function:

```
bert = BertModel.from_pretrained("bert-base-multilingual-uncased")
HL=512 # num neurons in added hidden layer
num_classes = 2

class Bert_Finetuned(nn.Module):
def __init__(self, bert):
    super(Bert_Finetuned, self).__init__()
    self.bert = bert
    self.dropout = nn.Dropout(0.1)
    self.relu = nn.ReLU()
    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(768, HL)
    self.fc2 = nn.Linear(HL, num_classes)
    self.softmax = nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1)

def forward(self, sentence_id, mask):
    _, cls_token = self.bert(sentence_id, attention_mask=mask, return_dict=False)
    x = self.fc1(cls_token)
    x = self.relu(x)
    x = self.dropout(x)
    x = self.fc2(x)
    x = self.softmax(x)
    return x

def train(model, optimizer, loss_function, train_dataloader):
'''Is called per epoch. Returns average loss, predicted class values, and true class values'''

print('Training...')
model.train()
total_loss = 0
total_preds = np.array([])
total_labels = np.array([])

for step, batch in enumerate(train_dataloader):
    
    # Progress update every 40 batches.
    if step % 40 == 0 and not step == 0:
        print('   Batch {}  of  {}.'.format(step, len(train_dataloader)))
    
    # get batch
    batch = [row.to(device) for row in batch]
    sentence_id, mask, labels = batch
    
    # clear any previously calculated gradients 
    model.zero_grad()

    # get training predictions                
    preds = model(sentence_id, mask)

    # get training loss     
    loss = loss_function(preds, labels)
    total_loss += float(loss.item())

    # calculate gradients
    loss.backward()
    
    # perform gradient clipping to prevent potential overflow during backprop influencing gradient descent calculations
    torch.nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), 1.0)

    # update weights and biases with AdamW
    optimizer.step()

    # model prediction are stored by 3070 now push them to CPU
    preds = preds.detach().cpu().numpy()

    # convert predicted probabilities to predicted class
    preds = np.argmax(preds, axis=1).flatten()

    # add predictions and labels per batch to numpy array to be able to calculate evaluation metrics if needed
    total_preds = np.hstack((total_preds, preds))
    total_labels = np.hstack((total_labels, labels.to('cpu').numpy().flatten()))

# Calculate the average loss over all of the batches.
avg_loss = total_loss/len(train_dataloader)

return avg_loss, total_preds, total_labels
```

Comment: Could you provide your code?

Comment: That error message is not readable. **Never** provide crucial information in images or links to external sites. Provide them as formatted text, as mentioned in [mcve], and https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: @TedKleinBergman I edited the question and replaced the image with code. Could you please remove the downvote? Many thanks :)

Comment: @Ivan Now, I included the architecture of one of the models and its train function.